# When to create multi-column indices in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, sql-order-by, query-optimization, where-clause

Assume I have a table in an SQLite database:

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    price INTEGER NOT NULL,
    updateTime INTEGER NOT NULL,
) [WITHOUT ROWID];
```

what indices should I create to optimize the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE price > ? ORDER BY updateTime DESC;
```

Do I create two indices:

```
CREATE INDEX i_1 ON orders(price);
CREATE INDEX i_2 ON orders(updateTime);
```

or one complex index?

```
CREATE INDEX i_3 ON orders(price, updateTime);
```

What can be query time complexity?

Comment: Unless the data is unusual, then the best index is `orders(updateTime, price)`, not `orders(proce, updateTime)`

Comment: *"What can be query time complexity?"* There is no single answer to this. The DB will optimize each query based on the situation. A single SELECT statement is not guaranteed to always produce the same query plan. The only thing you can do is create both indexes, and measure which query is faster for your data. (The fastest queries use a covering index, i.e. an index that contains all the columns in WHERE, the ORDER BY and the SELECT list. This way the query can be fulfilled by looking at the index alone, instead of using the index AND cross-referencing the base table.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview/WHERE Clause Analysis](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#where_clause_analysis):

> If an index is created using a statement like this:
>
> `CREATE INDEX idx_ex1 ON ex1(a,b,c,d,e,...,y,z);`
>
> Then the index *might*
> be used if the initial columns of the index (columns a, b, and so
> forth) appear in WHERE clause terms. The initial columns of the index
> must be used with the = or IN or IS operators. **The right-most column
> that is used can employ inequalities.**

As explained also in [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview/The Skip-Scan Optimization](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#skipscan) with an example:

> Because the left-most column of the index does not appear in the WHERE
> clause of the query, one is tempted to conclude that the index is not
> usable here. However, SQLite is able to use the index.

This means than if you create an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_orders ON orders(updateTime, price);
```

it *might* be used to optimize the `WHERE` clause even though `updateTime` does not appear there.

Also, from [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview/ORDER BY Optimizations](https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#order_by_optimizations):

> SQLite attempts to use an index to satisfy the ORDER BY clause of a
> query when possible. When faced with the choice of using an index to
> satisfy WHERE clause constraints or satisfying an ORDER BY clause,
> SQLite does the same cost analysis described above and chooses the
> index that it believes will result in the fastest answer.

Since `updateTime` is defined first in the composite index, the index *may* also be used to optimize the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: *"the index may also be used to optimize the `ORDER BY` clause"* - that depends on the selectivity of `updateTime`: If `updateTime` was largely the same over many records (low selectivity), the engine could make use of the fact that `price` is coming pre-ordered in certain slices of the index. But if `updateTime` had high selectivity (unique values for most records, the more likely case), then `price` will be effectively unordered on the index, and there would be no benefit from using it.

Comment: @Tomalak this is why I use *may* or *might*. The documentation mentions in several cases the cost analysis done by SQLite about the use of an existing index or a non-existing "Automatic Index": https://sqlite.org/optoverview.html#automatic_indexes.

Comment: I was not correcting you, that was more for the OP to read and think about. :)